# Returning Files Server Side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to be able to fetch the last/first 5 `.html` files from a particular folder in my Firebase hosting account (except for `index.html`). My client-side script would not know the URL/filename of the individual files. I simply want to fetch the last/first 5 `.html` files.

I will have an `index.html` file sitting there to serve up responses but I would like to avoid having to maintain that index.html file with the list of other files.

The use case is an `/articles` folder where I will have a myurl.com/articles.html landing page which shows a paginated view of articles.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: If you want to serve dynamic content via Firebase Hosting, you'll have to integrate with Cloud Functions for Firebase to write some backend code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Doug Stevenson:

If you want to serve dynamic content via Firebase Hosting, you'll have to integrate with Cloud Functions for Firebase to write some backend code. firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions